# How to Generate .xlsx file using PdfReport

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm using `PdfReport` library for generating reports as `.pdf` files.
PdfReport is a library built on Epplus and iTextsharp, that is why we chose this library- as we want to generate PDF and EXCEL files.

Currently we are able to generate the PDF file built can't seem to generate the Excel file.

There is not much help on Google related to this library.

[PdfReport](https://github.com/VahidN/PdfReport)

Here is my code

```
public class IListPdfReport
{
    public IPdfReportData CreatePdfReport(DataSet mTables)
    {
        return new PdfReport().DocumentPreferences(doc =>
        {
            doc.RunDirection(PdfRunDirection.LeftToRight);
            doc.Orientation(PageOrientation.Portrait);
            doc.PageSize(PdfPageSize.A4);
            doc.DocumentMetadata(new DocumentMetadata { Author = "Vahid", Application = "PdfRpt", Keywords = "IList Rpt.", Subject = "Test Rpt", Title = "Test" });
            doc.Compression(new CompressionSettings
            {
                EnableCompression = true,
                EnableFullCompression = true
            });
            doc.PrintingPreferences(new PrintingPreferences
            {
                ShowPrintDialogAutomatically = true
            });
        })
        .DefaultFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.Path(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"), "fonts\\arial.ttf"),
                       System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"), "fonts\\verdana.ttf"));
            fonts.Size(9);
            fonts.Color(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        })
        .PagesFooter(footer =>
        {
            footer.DefaultFooter(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        })
        .MainTableTemplate(template =>
        {
            template.BasicTemplate(BasicTemplate.AppleOrchardTemplate);
        })
        .MainTablePreferences(table =>
        {
            table.ColumnsWidthsType(TableColumnWidthType.FitToContent);
            table.NumberOfDataRowsPerPage(10);
        })
        .MainTableDataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.DataTable(mTables.Tables[2]);
        })
        .MainTableSummarySettings(summarySettings =>
        {
            summarySettings.OverallSummarySettings("Summary");
            summarySettings.PreviousPageSummarySettings("Previous Page Summary");
            summarySettings.PageSummarySettings("Page Summary");
        })
        .MainTableColumns(columns =>
        {
            columns.AddColumn(column =>
            {
                column.PropertyName("AssetSummaryReportDetailId");
                column.IsRowNumber(true);
                column.CellsHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                column.IsVisible(true);
                column.Order(0);
                column.Width(1);
                column.HeaderCell("AssetSummaryReportDetailId");
            });

            columns.AddColumn(column =>
            {
                column.PropertyName("AssetId");
                column.IsRowNumber(true);
                column.CellsHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                column.IsVisible(true);
                column.Order(1);
                column.Width(2);
                column.HeaderCell("AssetId");
            });

            columns.AddColumn(column =>
            {
                column.PropertyName("CategoryId");
                column.IsRowNumber(true);
                column.CellsHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center);
                column.IsVisible(true);
                column.Order(1);
                column.Width(2);
                column.HeaderCell("CategoryId");
            });




        })
        .MainTableEvents(events =>
        {
            events.DataSourceIsEmpty(message: "There is no data available to display.");
        })
        .Export(export =>
        {

// This line here should generate the Excel file, but it is not creating the Excel file
            export.ToExcel(description: "Demo", fileName: "usmandemo.xlsx", worksheetName: "worksheet1", footer: "footer");
        })
        .Generate(data => data.AsPdfFile(string.Format("{0}\\A_RptIListSample-{1}.pdf", AppPath.ApplicationPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))));

    }
```

Comment: The easiest way is to generate a CSV file.

Comment: @Mafii the problem is not generating Excel with any other library - we are using PDF Report library as mentioned in question - we have set export.ToExcel(description: "Demo", fileName: "usmandemo.xlsx", worksheetName: "worksheet1", footer: "footer"); - but it is  not generating the Excel File

Comment: @Kalten how to do that with PDFReport library?

Comment: @Mafii it is built on EPPLUS and iTextSharp - so yes I can as EPPLUS is an excel library

Answer (score 0):

i've never used that particular library, so can't make any suggestions on how to use it,
However if you want to create an xlsx file with the data you can do so with out going through their service

The new Office File format is called Office Open XML Format, and its common between all office applications there is a MSDN guide here that will help you

[Creating Documents by Using the Open XML Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: As mentioned in question we are using PDFReport - which is built on EPPLus and iTextSharp - so we are able to generate PDF but not excel format

Comment: if you look at that guide you can build the Excel file with out having to pass though the 3rd party library, reducing the level of complexity and letting you generate PDF's from the PDF library and xlsx directly, if you just want support for that 1 library then i would suggest raising a support request with them directly